# How do I show the current page title or label?

Tags: css, html, blogger

How to show the current page title or label?

I have tried with below code -

```
<data:blog.searchLabel/>
```

Display the label when you are on URL search label only. I need a code that displays HOMEPAGE when you are on homepage URL and shows Label of posts When you are on blogger posts !!

I couldn't do that so I called another div that display the tags but its super bad since it gets doubled when I call it for no reason.

```
$(function(){
    $('.label-head a').clone().appendTo('.repheader');
   });

<div class='tm-menu'>
  <div class='body-row repheader'><data:blog.searchLabel/></div>
  <div class=label-head>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself.

1. I found two `div`s so I deleted one of them.
2. I found blogger tag that display the page title, [here](https://sneeit.com/blogger-basic-global-layout-data-tags/) is a link which you might find helpful.